# Major product of Crossed-Cannizzaro Reaction between benzaldehyde and formaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I came across a question:

> Predict the major product when conc. $\ce{NaOH}$ is added to a mixture of $\ce{PhCHO}$ and $\ce{HCHO}$.

According to me, as $\ce{HCHO}$ is less hindered and $\ce{>C=O}$ of $\ce{HCHO}$ is more reactive, so the major products must be $\ce{CH3ONa}$ and $\ce{HCOONa}$. The hydride transfer should be from one Formaldehyde molecule to the other.

However, the answer was given as $\ce{HCOONa}$ and $\ce{PhCH2ONa}$. Is there a mistake on my part?

Comment: Rate determining step of Cannizaro is the hydride transfer and not nucleophilic attack

Comment: Why would the hydride prefer transferring to the PHCHO?

Comment: Exactly...  Thats how I get HCOONa... But I am concerned about the Alcohol product... HCOONa matches with my answer... PhCH2ONa does not

Comment: So what happens to the benzaldehyde>

Comment: It might also form some PHCH2ONa... But the major product must be CH2ONa according to me... And that isn't the question what happens to benzaldehyde. What is the major product is what the question demands

Comment: See [this earlier](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42816/crossed-cannizzaro-reaction/42836#42836) Q&A.

Comment: Ok but I still dont understand why the cross reaction is favored over one formaldehyde molecule reacting to the other

Comment: Effectiively there is no free formaldehyde to accept hydride.